# Google retornando 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, google-maps

Meu webservice efetua uma requisição ao maps.google.com porém retorna acontece exception
System.Net.WebException com mensagem 403 Forbidden

Porém a URL executa normalmente via navegador. O que pode ser?

```
[WebMethod]
public string teste()
{
    string url = @"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=-28.2773357297022,-52.7852053516473&destination=-19.7779008,-47.9249145&mode=driving&waypoints=-26.8727562,-49.1010188|-25.530283,-49.2949339|-23.4841434977362,-46.7853496799363|&sensor=false&client=gme-meuID&signature=G3GSye-fxYY-GIDq-z2TIO8FI2A=";   
    HttpWebRequest _HttpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    _HttpReq.Method = "GET";
    var response = _HttpReq.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    return sReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: [Achei isto aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq?hl=pt-br#signature_403). Seria o caso?

Comment: Não se encaixa em nenhum dos casos, pois a url tem o ClientID, está assinada e a assinatura está correta uma vez que abre normalmente se eu ir pelo browser.

Comment: Observe [nesta página](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices) alguns padrões, como por exemplo o domínio utilizado, que é o `maps.googleapis.com`. Outra coisa é a forma como você está assinando a requisição, veja um exemplo em `C#` no final desta página. *Recomendo você não exibir sua chave de assinatura aqui, como próprio alerta de segurança do Google.*

Comment: O domínio na verdade redireciona para o maps.google.com. só exibi o ClientID que é aberto, a chave privada realmente não deve ser exibida e está bem guarda na minha aplicação ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Descobri o problema ao verificar que WebRequest.Create tem 2 versões, uma com string e outra com Uri. Após isto verifiquei que o endereço real que é solicitado é diferente da string passada, uma vez que o caracter | deve ser convertido para um caractere de escape para ser uma uri válida.

String:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=-28.2773357297022,-52.7852053516473&destination=-19.7779008,-47.9249145&mode=driving&waypoints=**-26.8727562,-49.1010188|-25.530283,-49.2949339|-23.4841434977362,-46.7853496799363|**&sensor=false&client=gme-meuID&signature=G3GSye-fxYY-GIDq-z2TIO8FI2A=

---

_HttpReq.AbsoluteUri:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=-28.2773357297022,-52.7852053516473&destination=-19.7779008,-47.9249145&mode=driving&waypoints=**-26.8727562,-49.1010188%7C-25.530283,-49.2949339%7C-23.4841434977362,-46.7853496799363%7C**&sensor=false&client=gme-meuID&signature=G3GSye-fxYY-GIDq-z2TIO8FI2A=

---

No navegador isto não é necessário, porém na web request sim, portanto antes da assinatura da url deve ser usado o Uri.EscapeDataString na parte dos waypoints.

Assinando com a uri correta:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=-28.2773357297022,-52.7852053516473&destination=-19.7779008,-47.9249145&mode=driving&waypoints=-26.8727562,-49.1010188%7C-25.530283,-49.2949339%7C-23.4841434977362,-46.7853496799363%7C&sensor=false&client=gme-meuID&signature=**RQ5bftPp55lJjfoibr7kQCWBwN0**=